# RHEL 7.4 not loading php extension for httpd and unable to configure it also

Tags: php, linux, apache, httpd.conf, rhel7

I have a fresh server installed with httpd web server and php as CLI. I am able to execute any PHP script in console but when I put the same in a file and call it in browser, it outputs PHP script as it is.

Basically httpd is not parsing PHP script since the extension or module like mod_php is not available. I do not see any files with .so extension in the `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d`

```
/etc/php.d is empty
```

and

```
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d has
[root@ip-10-227-85-145 conf.modules.d]# ll
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3739 Jun 22  2018 00-base.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  139 Jun 22  2018 00-dav.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   41 Jun 22  2018 00-lua.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  742 Jun 22  2018 00-mpm.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  957 Jun 22  2018 00-proxy.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   88 Jun 22  2018 00-systemd.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  451 Jun 22  2018 01-cgi.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   59 Mar 31  2016 10-auth_openidc.conf
```

I am clueless what to do. `yum install php5-mcrypt` is not working.It gave me some error.

Comment: I am not sure whether you have install libapache2-mod-php module, please check once.

Comment: I do not know how to install mod_php in RHEL 7.4.

Answer (score 0):

RHEL dosen't support mod_php. It uses fsm/fcgi - this is mentioned here - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-php56-apache-rhel72/